# SSRS - Remove seconds from Time field

Tags: reporting-services, expression, rdl

How do I remove seconds from Time field?
I tried:

```
=Rset(Fields!hr_saida.Value,5) = return #Error
=TimeValue(Fields!hr_saida.Value) = return #Error
=FormatDateTime(CDate(Fields!hr_saida.Value),"hh:mm") = return #Error
```

I also tried set my text box property to Number > 13:30, but still shows "hh:mm:ss"
How do I remove? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option in addition to the one from @Yuriy is:

```
=Format(Fields!hr_saida.Value, "HH:mm")
```

for 24 Hour time

or:

```
=Format(Fields!hr_saida.Value, "hh:mm")
```

for AM/PM.

If your field isn't DateTime you may need to use `CDate()` as well.

**Edit after comment**

Try:

```
=Left(Fields!hr_saida.Value.ToString(), 5)
```

`RSet` also works with `ToString`.

That works for 24 hour time - you could use something like:

```
=CDate(Fields!hr_saida.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm")
```

for AM/PM.

In my testing I was getting similar errors like:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

and

> Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'Date' is not valid.

I guess the conclusion here is that SSRS *really* dislikes the SQL Server time datatype.

Comment: If the field actually contains a datetime value, then use the format property of the textbox (set to "HH:mm"), so that exports will preserve the value.

Comment: @JamieF, as always a useful comment! For just displaying the value that's probably the best possible solution; actually using `Format` would be most useful when being appended to a larger string using the value.

Comment: My field is Time(7), i tried before CDate() but still get the same error

Comment: @JamieF Maybe I'm doing something really wrong, and i'm sorry for that but the return was "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: Thank you @IanPreston ! The last expression worked pretty good!!

Comment: `=Left(Fields!hr_saida.Value.ToString(), 5)` I used this one. And i think ssrs dislikes time dataype too, because I used before (not time datatype) some expressions and was cool for me, but when the datatype was Time.... Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `4` option for `FormatDateTime` function.

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!hr_saida.Value, 4)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Still returning "#Error"

Comment: What type is `Fields!hr_saida.Value` ? What happens if you simple output `=Fields!hr_saida.Value,` ?

Comment: I get "hh:mm:ss" and the type is "time(7)"

Comment: Please try method of @JammieF in the comment below - set format of actual textbox

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble returning what I wanted without error. I was already casting a datetime field to time so I just grabbed the left 5 characters (in SQL query) to trim off seconds. Not elegant, but got the job done.

So `EndTime` in my table is a datetime datatype with values like `2020-03-30 09:34:00.000`.
All I needed was short time without seconds so:

```
left(cast(EndTime as time),5) [End]
```

This changed report column outputs like `09:34:00` to `09:34` which is all I needed.